# Иероглифы перед текстом, выведенным из файла в MessageBox

Tags: winapi, c++

Изучаю работу с файлами. При записи слова "Новое слово" вроде всё нормально. Но при выводе перед "новым словом" выходит строчка из одного китайского иероглифа. Что это может быть и как его победить.

```
HANDLE hFile;
TCHAR slovo[] = _T("Новое слово"), P[30];
hFile = CreateFile(_T("proba2.zzz"), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD HH;
WriteFile(hFile, slovo, sizeof(slovo), &HH, NULL);
ReadFile(hFile, P, sizeof(P), &HH, NULL);
MessageBox(NULL, P, _T("Win32 Guided Tour"), NULL);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: Случаем, не [BOM](http://wikipedia.org/BOM) ли это?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С вашим буфером `P` вообще не производятся никакие операции, потому что в коде *допущены 3 грубые ошибки.*

---

- Вы невнимательно прочитали [**описание функции `CreateFile`**.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858.aspx) В случае параметра `CREATE_NEW` будет возвращаться ошибка, если файл уже существует *(то есть, после первого запуска программы ваша программа перестает что-либо делать вообще)*.

> Правильный параметр для вашего случая - **`OPEN_ALWAYS`**.

- В случае, если вы хотите читать и писать одновременно, необходимо устанавливать параметр `dwDesiredAccess` функции `CreateFile` в **`GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE`**
- Нельзя что-то записать с помощью `hFile`, а потом считать это обратно, не перемещая `file pointer`

> После вызова `WriteFile` необходимо добавить строчку **[`SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx)**

---

*Исправленный фрагмент программы:*

```
hFile = CreateFile(_T("proba2.zzz"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD HH;
WriteFile(hFile, slovo, sizeof(slovo), &HH, NULL);
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
ReadFile(hFile, P, sizeof(P), &HH, NULL);
```